# update database server with ajax and perl

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

I have set of code for updating a password in the table, here I'm using AJAX to update the password and get the popup screen on corresponding execution.When using that code with my application it is executing properly but I didn't get the output(password is not updated into table). I don't get any error either.

Html page Code

```
<html>
<head>
<div><IMG src="karvy.jpg" ALT="image"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//Browser Support Code


var xmlHttp;
function fetch_javaScript(usr,oldpassword,newpassword,repassword)
        {
        xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp==null)
                {
                alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
                return;
                }
        var usr = document.getElementById('usr').value;
        var oldpassword = document.getElementById('oldpassword').value;
        var newpassword = document.getElementById('newpassword').value;
        var repassword = document.getElementById('repassword').value;


        var url="changepwd1.pl";
        url=url+"?usr=" + usr;
        url=url+"&oldpassword=" + oldpassword;
        url=url+"&oldpassword=" + newpassword;
        url=url+"&repassword=" + repassword;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
        xmlHttp.open("POST",url,false);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        }

function stateChanged()
        {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                }

        }

function GetXmlHttpObject()
        {
        var xmlHttp=null;
        try
        {
 // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e)
        {
 //Internet Explorer
                try
                {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                 catch (e)
                {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
        }
        return xmlHttp;
        }
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#D2B9D3">
<form name='myForm'>
<center><table> <tr><td>
<div style="width:400px;height:280px;border:3px solid black;">
<center><h4>Please Enter your Password's</h4>

<p><b>User Name</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<INPUT TYPE=text NAME="usr" id = "usr" size = "15" maxlength = "15" tabindex = "1"/></p>
<p><b>Old Password:</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<INPUT TYPE=PASSWORD NAME="oldpassword" id = "oldpassword" size = "15" maxlength = "15" tabindex = "1"/></p>
<p><b>Password:</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<INPUT TYPE=PASSWORD NAME="newpassword" id = "newpassword" size = "15" maxlength = "15" tabindex = "1"/></p>
<p><b>Re-Password:</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<INPUT TYPE=PASSWORD NAME="repassword" id = "repassword" size = "15" maxlength = "15" tabindex = "1"/></p>
<input type="submit" id="val" value="Submit" align="middle" method="POST"  onclick="fetch_javaScript()"/><INPUT TYPE="reset" name = "Reset" value = "Reset"/>
<p>Main Menu <A HREF = login.pl>click here</A></p>
</center>
</div>
</td></tr></table></center>
</form>

<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
<!--<div id="myDiv"></div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Perl Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new;

print $cgi->header;
print $cgi->start_html("Password Form");
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $request;

########################################        Query String


                if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET")
                        {
                        $request = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
                        }
                elsif ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
                        {
                        read(STDIN, $request,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}) || die "Could not get query\n";
                        }

#$request="usr=sairam&oldpassword=password123&oldpassword=123456&repassword=123456";
my $j=0;
my ($i,@update_value,@value);
my @parameter=split(/&/,$request);

                for $i (@parameter)
                        {
                                        @value=split(/=/, $i);
                                        $update_value[$j] =$value[1];
                                        $j++;
                        }




                my $user=$update_value[0];
                my $oldpward=$update_value[1];
                my $newpward=$update_value[2];
                my $repward=$update_value[3];

 #$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if ($user)
        {
##      Database Connectivity
                my $DSN = q/dbi:ODBC:SQLSERVER/;
                my $uid = q/ivr/;
                my $pwd = q/ivr/;
                my $DRIVER = "Freetds";
                my %attr = (PrintError => 1,RaiseError => 1,);
                my $dbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$uid,$pwd,\%attr) or die $DBI::errstr;;

                my $sth=$dbh->prepare("select password from rpt_account_information where username='$user'") or die("Query didn't work");
                $sth->execute();
                my $oldpassworddb=$sth->fetchrow();
                #               check pass
                if ($oldpward==$oldpassworddb)
                        {
                        #       check twonew pass
                        if ($newpward==$repward)
                                {
                                #success
                                #change pass in db
                                 if (length($newpward)>10||length($newpward)<4)   #Here is the code
                                        {
                                         print  "<script>alert('Password must be betwwen 4 & 10')</script>";
                                        }

                                else
                                        {
                                        my $p_update = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE rpt_account_information SET password=? WHERE username=?");
                                        $p_update->execute($newpward,$user);
                                        #session_destroy();
                                        print 'Your pass has benn changed.<a href="login.pl">Return</a> to the main page';
                                        }
                                }
                        else
                                {
                                        print "<script>alert('New Pass does not match')</script>";
                                }
                        }
                else
                        {
                        print "<script>alert('Old Pass does not match')</script>";
                        }

}
```

This is my complete code but I'm not able to find out error or output
Please help me...

Comment: You're using `CGI.pm`, why on earth are you trying to decode your query string / post data manually?!

Comment: I see lines like `if ($oldpward==$oldpassworddb)`. If the values are strings (guessing from the variable names), then you have to use `eq` instead. BTW, if you see inexplicable behavior, then you should also add `use warnings;` next to `use strict;`.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a value to `innerHTML` that contains a `<script>` element won't cause that script to be executed.

As a work around, you could parse the JavaScript out of it in JS and then `eval` it, but you would be better off dealing in structured data (e.g. JSON) and leaving your presentation logic to JavaScript already in the page.